# How to ensure and force ownership of a handle to prevent unwanted CloseHandle calls?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++14, handle

#### TL;DR

Say I implement a class that implements an API that returns a `HANDLE`.
Say my class is the owner of the `HANDLE` and responsible to create it, update it and close it.

How do I prevent callers of my API to close my handle and break my design?

#### BACKGROUND

`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` is an expensive call and must be used intelligently.
I have many projects in my solution and each of them calls `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` carelessly.

I want to implement an wrapper class that provides "smart" access to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.

My class will be the owner of the `HADNLE` returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and will update it (re-call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`) when needed (not yet fully define when it is needed).

For sake of simplicity let's assume my application is a single process & thread and my class has one instance only.

Comment: If the `HANDLE` is owned by your class implementation, simply don't hand it out to clients. If you need to provide clients with ways to communicate with your class, give them a handle type of your making, that your class can map to the actual `HANDLE`, without that ever leaving your class.

Comment: If you hide the implementation of HANDLE in a normal way (pimpl, for example) you should not have a lot of problems. The HANDLE does not create or remove anything, and you just just 2 API calls for creating and destroying. But I supose I did not get something.

Comment: @IInspectable clients of my wrapper class needs the `HANDLE` to be able to use many other WINAPIs. I don't want to encapsulate the entire APIs family that uses that handle.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether you like it or not. If you need to model strict ownership of data, you cannot pass that data out of the owner. That's called a *"leaky abstraction"*, and one of the issues with this is losing control over owned resources.

Comment: @AlexF that's a great idea. So callers gets a VALID handle to use and if they accidentally call `CloseHandle()` - my stored `HANDLE` is still valid. am I correct?

Comment: How can a client close the origial `HANDLE`? It only get a copy of the original one. client may and should close the copy but the original stays valid and should be closed by the wrapper class.

Comment: So what is the purpose of `DuplicateHandle` then? (compare to just assignment)

Comment: you of course can call `DuplicateHandle` before pass handle to clients, and oblige clients close this handle. but what be if they not close it ? what be if clients call your code with invalid params ? what be if client code incorrect and crash process ? simply pass original handle to clients and it must not close it. if client code incorrect - this is not your problem. it always can be incorrect and break all

Comment: @RbMm I agree. However, the cons of a client closing my original handle and "breaking" my class are much worst than the cons of a client not closing the cloned handle. don't you agree?

Comment: also exist cons of extra calls to DuplicateHandle/CloseHandle. but you can use `DuplicateHandle` and pass this handle to client. are this is better or not - not direct winapi question

Comment: also as "solution" you can call `SetHandleInformation` with `HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE` for protect your handle from close. and remove this flag yourself at the end. guess clients not try do this too ))

Answer (score 4):

> Say I implement a class that implements an API that returns a HANDLE

You broke your design by returning the handle. The users of your wrapper should not care for the handle but for the data that they want like the module list in your case. Expose an API that can return such data to your users.

```
class snapshot
{
    public:
    snapshot()
    {
        m_handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(...);
    }
    ~snapshot()
    {
        CloseHandle(m_handle);
    }
    getModules()
    {
        // use m_handle to return a list of modules.
    }
    private:
    HANDLE m_handle;
};
```

Comment: This is one way to go but I don't want to encapsulate the entire APIs family that uses that handle. It seems like a major overkill and really leads me to believe that my design is flawed.

Comment: @idanshmu What entire API family are you referring to? In my opinion since you are the owner of the handle, you should be the one to control how it is used. If you want to expose the handle any how then you have to trust the users of your API to not meddle with the handle.

Comment: Exposing a member of a class does not imply exposing ownership or fully trusting callers. In my case I want to expose member with only "reading" access. same as you return a const member. Microsoft could have easily bring the const concept to their `HANDLE`

Comment: @ida: You cannot protect a `HANDLE`, it's just a pointer underneath. If a client wants to call `CloseHandle` on it, there is nothing to prevent that. If you don't want your clients to close the handle, don't hand it out. Making the `HANDLE` `const` doesn't by you anything; it's just a value after all, and Microsoft could not have done anything to provide what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use DuplicateHandle and *require* that the caller call CloseHandle. Other than that you must trust the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. So long as you are unwilling to fully encapsulate all uses of the `HANDLE`, external code which can access the `HANDLE` directly can close it. This is no different from being able to do `delete smart_ptr.get();`.

C++ can protect you from accidental misuse. It cannot protect you from *perfidy*. If a user who is using a smart-handle class didn't get the memo that the smart-handle class is the owner of the `HANDLE`, there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to implement that class, I would simply write the method `Enumerate` and would call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, another set of functions and then `CloseHandle`. The `HANDLE` won't be part of the class itself, but local to the `Enumerate` method. 
The enumeration would fill a required struct (user-defined) and would create a `vector` of that struct (or (`unordered_`)`map`, if some PID -> ProcessInformation access is required.). 
The class would facilitate methods to get that *enumerated* data. For a first-class C++ class, I would actually implement `begin` and `end` methods so that class/object can be used with range-based `for` loop.

Why do you really need to *delay* in the actual processing of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`? By the time a genuine caller calls some *safe* Win32 API on that handle, the state of running processes would have changed. If the object of your class stays for long(er) then all you've is stale/inconsistent information against that handle.